# how to integrate AdMob in iPhone application

Tags: ios, admob

I want to implement AdMob functionality in current project. I am getting some issues to implement this technology. Could you please help me on this?

I am integrating AdMob in my iOS application first time. During this process when add AdMob SDK into app , following errors appears.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADDevice.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[GADOpener openInAppStore:fallbackURLString(inlove) in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I think StoreKit Framework And CoreTelephony Framework you have not added..

Comment: You should accept answer which helped you if not then better let us know what happened, so one can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [Google AdMob guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios)

You have to import following frameworks -

```
AdSupport,
AudioToolbox,
AVFoundation,
CoreGraphics,
CoreTelephony,
MessageUI,
StoreKit,
SystemConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to import all of these frameworks in your app for AdMob integration

1) AudioTollbox.framework,

2) MediaPlayer.framework

3) MessageUI.framework,

4) SystemConfiguration.framework,

5) StoreKit Framework

6) CoreTelephony Framework